# Hibernate 3.6 configuration with Spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a Maven project with dependencies on Spring 2.5 and Hibernate 3.6. However, I am experiencing a problem on this portion of code:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static
{
    try
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The following are the problems:

- ServiceRegistry class is not found in library;
- ServiceRegistryBuilder class is not found in library;
- configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry) cannot resolved type

Are there any alternative code for this **without** upgrading and downgrading to another Spring and Hibernate versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I used:

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();

    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = factory.openSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to maven search repo sites like : http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=hibernate

and search for "hibernate", and you'll see relevant version mvn-dependency-snippets:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.10.Final

copy paste it to your pom, it should work.